# How can i save CGContextRef after calling UIGraphicsBeginImageContext?

Tags: iphone, ios

I would like to be able to save the `CGContextRef` after calling `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` to use it later in a background thread which is responsible for delivering images every 1/25 seconds.

The problem i faced while using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` every time the selector gets called from background thread is that it takes time to create the context and i fail to draw an image every 1/25 seconds.

I tried using `CGBitmapContextCreate` but i dont get the same image quality of that created by the `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext()-->[image drawInRect]`

I tried calling `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` on `viewDidLoad` and save the `CGContextRef` right after it so i can use it in later calls but the context is getting released somehow and so i get the "`CGContextDrawImage: invalid context 0x0`" error right after calling `[image drawInRect]`
and the image i get from `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()` is `null` afterwards.

Is it possible to Begin a single image context to use throughout the lifetime of the application? if yes, how? or else please advise if there are other options to save my context.

Answer (score 0):

First, it's a confusing to create a graphics context on one thread and then pass it to a different thread.  Just create the graphics context on the background thread in the first place.

Second, since `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` manipulates UIKit's graphics context stack, it's confusing to try to save the `CGContext` that it creates and use it later (presumably after you've called `UIGraphicsEndImageContext`).  It might work if you retain the `CGContextRef`; I haven't tried it.

What you should do is just use the Core Graphics APIs directly.  Create your context using `CGBitmapContextCreate`, get a `CGImage` from it using `CGBitmapContextCreateImage`, and convert the `CGImage` to a `UIImage` using `+[UIImage imageWithCGImage:]` if necessary.

Comment: I agree with you rob about using CGBitmapContextCreateImage on the same thread. This is what i did! But the problem with this method is with the CGContextDrawImage i call on the context. It is drawing the image upside down and the colors are wrong :S